# Problems Creating tables in MYSQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, create-table, error-code, mysql-5.7

would really like some help trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I have searched through several other questions but could not find anything wrong in my CREATE statement that others had.

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
'Client_ID' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'Client_Name' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
'Class' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
'Pre-Billing' BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
'Email' VARCHAR(100),
'Phone_Number' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
'Address' VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
'Last_Updated' timestamp default now() on update now(),
'Date_Added' timestamp default now(),
PRIMARY KEY ('Client_ID')
);
```

The error I am getting is

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Client_ID' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'Client_Name' VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL, ' at line 2
```

If you could please advise that would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if you could [edit] to mention what things you checked for, specifically.

Comment: Try it again without quoting your column names.

Comment: You are using single quotes for column names.  This is wrong.  I consider this a simple typographical error and vote to close such questions.

Comment: Thank you for the help, sorry to be a burden with such a minuscule question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the single quotes around the column names and change the hyphen in "Pre-Billing" to an underscore "Pre_Billing", this should fix it.

Comment: Awesome Thank you!
Works perfect.